# DB2 Connection using C#.Net - Ms Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to connect `Db2` through `c#.net`

```
DB2Command MyDB2Command = null;    

String MyDb2ConnectionString = "database=<alias>;uid=<username>;pwd=<password>;";

DB2Connection MyDb2Connection = new DB2Connection(MyDb2ConnectionString);

MyDb2Connection.Open();
```

Getting below error on `MyDb2Connection.open()`:

> SQL1159  Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 9.7.4,

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

In application folder I have already put `db2app.dll` and `db2app64.dll`

`Db2` Version: `9.7.4`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 10, tokens 0.0.0, 9.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118367/sql1159-initialization-error-with-db2-net-data-provider-reason-code-10-tokens)

Comment: @vahdet the ticket you have mentioned is issue related to IIS. I haven't hosted yet.