# Getting SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason 2 in .NET runtime but it works in Classic ASP.NET Framework runtime. Why?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, db2, clr, coreclr

I get the below exception when trying to access a .NET Framework class library which has the data access code from a .NET Core API project.

**Exception: SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason 2, tokens C:..\bin\db2app64.dll, , Process Owner: ...**

This exception occurred exactly when I tried to open a DB2Connection in my code as below,

**Stack Trace:**

```
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.Open(DB2Connection connection, ref string szConnectionString, ref DB2ConnSettings ppSettings, ref object ppConn)
IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.Open()
```

**Code:**

```
obj = New DB2Connection(connectionString)
obj.Open() --> Exception occurred
```

**Note:** *This library worked seamlessly when I tried to reference it from a classic ASP.NET Framework Web API (which uses .NET Framework CLR). But when I tried to access the same class library from .NET Core + Extensions (which uses .NET Core CLR), I get this exception (This occurred even after I used all the necessary APIs from the Windows Compatibility Pack).
*

*I have already gone through this chain [SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484349/sql1159-initialization-error-with-db2-net-data-provider-reason-code-2), but, my thirst is different.*

**All I need to know is a solution to make this work in .NET Core CLR and why does it occur in .NET Core CLR and not in classic ASP.NET Framework CLR**

Comment: You need to install db2.net driver for .net core from Nuget package. Install and it will work then. Let me know once you tried

Comment: DId you mean this IBM.Data.DB2.Core nuget package?

Comment: yes choose version based on your .net core version. It will display on right side.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I installed IBM.Data.DB2.Core for .net core and found a new folder by the name clidriver under _../project/bin/_. This folder in tern has a bin folder (_../project/bin/release/clidriver/bin/db2app64.dll_) which has the db2app64.dll file. But the CoreCLR produces the same error _SQL1159 Initialization error with DB2 .NET Data Provider, reason 2, tokens C:..\bin\db2app64.dll_ by searching it in the bin folder. Is there any way that I can configure it to find the file in the specified directory. Or should I manually copy paste the dll into the bin folder?

Comment: You have to copy it manually for this particular driver :)